# Retriving previous version of a content using API in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working on Ektron 8.6.

How can i retrive the previous version of a Content by passing the Content Id using API?
Previous version in the sense the content data before editing(there may be multiple edits for a content).Is it able to retrieve these different versions through API?

Whether any utility is there in ektron to directly convert Content to a doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```
var contentManager = new ContentManager();
var historyList = contentManager.GetHistoryList(contentId);
foreach(var historyData in historyList)
{
     var contentData = contentManager.GetContentByHistoryId(historyData.Id);
}
```

The relevant namespace you'll want to take can be found here: Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Whether any utility is there in ektron to directly convert Content to a doc?

Comment: One more Qn,what is the meaning of the word "Ektron"?

Comment: Can you look into these un-answered Qns in DevCenter? http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=40264

Comment: The name 'ektron' itself doesn't really mean anything, it's a name not based on any word really.